# How can I bulk import into galleries?

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery, bulk-import

I have a large number of photo galleries in a database-driven site that I want to migrate into WordPress.  I can get the metadata and associations out of the database.

Is there a way to bulk import the photos into WordPress and generate photo galleries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't think it was an elegant solution, but this is what I did. I wrote a plugin that:

- Looped through the galleries in the old database
- Created a post for each gallery (I chose to use the envira gallery plugin) in the format used by a sample envira gallery post
- Looped through all the images in each old gallery and attached them to the new gallery post with appropriate metadata